# How to make a graphic line into JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I use Eclipse, and I want make a graphic line into JFrame by following code:

```
public void Makeline () {
    Graphics g=new Graphics(); // has error
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 20, 20));
}
```

but give followin error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type Graphics
```

Comment: Graphics is abstract, you have to extend it implementing the methods required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Graphics` is an abstract class, defining the requirements of the overall API.

Painting in Swing is done within the context of the paint chain. This is typically performed within the `paintComponent` method of components that extend from `JComponent`

Take a look at [Perfoming Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

You can also use a `BufferdImage` to generate a `Graphics` context, but you still need somewhere to draw the image, so it comes down what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to overwrite the paintComponent method, but the JFrame isn't a JComponent, so instead of JFrame, use JPanel and then add the JPanel to the JFrame.

```
paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g)

    //here goes your code
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @SamieyMehdi How are you implementing it?

Comment: @SamieyMehdi My comment was not answer to your question but suggestion to improve this answer.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi Start by taking a a read through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: @SamieyMehdi You don't, it's called automatically for you when ever the repaint manager decides that your component needs to be updated. Take the time to have a read through the tutorial I linked in my previous comment and answer

Answer (score 0):

Graphics is an abstract class. You can't instantiate following way.

```
 Graphics g=new Graphics();
```

To access `Graphics2D`, first you need to override `paint(Graphics)` method.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
}
```

Comment: No. 1- You should avoid overriding paint, generally, but especially of top level containers. 2- You should always call super.paintXxx